# Referencing cout to a variable location (file or cmd)

Tags: c++, output

I would like to write output either to the cmd window or a log file using one function only. The best I found to do this was this treed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428630/assigning-cout-to-a-variable-name).

So this code (minor changes from the referenced source) works for me to 90%:

```
void outputTest(){
cout << "Testing a new version of output." << endl;
std::ofstream realOutFile;
bool outFileRequested = true;
if(outFileRequested)
    realOutFile.open("foo.txt", std::ios::out);

std::ostream & outFile = (outFileRequested ? realOutFile : std::cout);

outFile << "test" << endl;
keep_window_open();
}
```

Now instead of "foo.txt" I would like to write the file to another location. So I added the following:

```
string LogFile = config_.outputFiles+config_.projectName; //+"/RoomData.log"
ofstream realOutFile;
if (logFileRequested && config_.saveLogs){
    realOutFile.open(LogFile+"/foo.txt", ios::out);
}
std::ostream & outFile = (logFileRequested ? realOutFile : cout);
```

I also tried passing only a string but in both cases I get that the function call does not match.

Is there a way to fix that? 
Why is passing a string different than passing "string content"?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. Sorry I did not het the C++ code formatted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see next link for function prototype: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

open function receives const char* as 1st parameter.
This way it should work ->

```
string LogFile = config_.outputFiles+config_.projectName; //+"/RoomData.log"
ofstream realOutFile;
if (logFileRequested && config_.saveLogs){
    LogFile += "/foo.txt";
    realOutFile.open(LogFile.c_str(), ios::out);
}

std::ostream & outFile = (logFileRequested ? realOutFile : cout);
```