# How to assign istringstream and ifstream to an istream variable?

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream, istringstream

I want to have a variable of type `istream` which can hold either the contents of a file or a string. The idea is that if no file was specified, the variable of type `istream` would be assigned with a string.

```
std::ifstream file(this->_path)
```

and

```
std::istringstream iss(stringSomething);
```

to

```
std::istream is
```

I've tried just assigning them to the `istream` variable like I would with other objects that inherit from the same base class, but that didn't work.

How to assign `istringstream` and `ifstream` to an `istream` variable?

Comment: [Very similar, but with output streams](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38454951/3552770).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base class pointers can point to derived class data. `std::istringstream` and `std::ifstream` both derived from `std::istream`, so we can do:

```
//Note that std::unique_ptr is better that raw pointers
std::unique_ptr<std::istream> stream;

//stream holds a file stream
stream = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(std::ifstream{ this->_path });

//stream holds a string
stream = std::make_unique<std::istringstream>(std::istringstream{});
```

Now you just have to extract the content using

```
std::string s;
(*stream) >> s;
```

Comment: I would probably use `std::unique_ptr<std::istream> stream_owner;` and then `std::istream& stream = *stream_owner;`, allowing the familiar `stream >> s` syntax.

Comment: The `make_unique()` calls can be simplified a little: `stream = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(_path);` and `stream = std::make_unique<std::istringstream>();`  Also note that `std::unique_ptr` is new in C++11, but `std::make_unique` is new in C++14.

Answer (score 8):

You can't assign to a `std::istream` but you can bind to a reference like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::istringstream test_data(R"~(

some test data here
instead of in an external
file.

)~");

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    // if we have a parameter use it
    std::string filename = argv[1] ? argv[1] : "";

    std::ifstream ifs;

    // try to open a file if we have a filename
    if(!filename.empty())
        ifs.open(filename);

    // This will ONLY fail if we tried to open a file
    // because the filename was not empty    
    if(!ifs)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // if we have an open file bind to it else bind to test_data
    std::istream& is = ifs.is_open() ? static_cast<std::istream&>(ifs) : test_data;

    // use is here
    for(std::string word; is >> word;)
    {
        std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
        std::cout << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: a complete example for choosing a default stream (e.g. `std::cin`) if a file was not supplied, and to assign it to a variable of type `std::istream`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a page out of the standard library: don't assign a value; assign a reference.  That's probably what you want anyway.

```
std::istringstream iss(stringSomething);
std::istream& input(iss);
```

Because streams carry a lot of state, copying them is fraught with semantic questions.  Consider for example what **tellg** should report in the copy after the original calls **seekg**.  References by contrast answer the question transparently.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you cannot assign an object of type `Child` to a variable of type `Parent`, even if `Child` inherits from `Parent`. You can assign a *pointer* of type Child to a pointer of type *Parent*, however. You may want to consider dynamically allocating the objects.

Answer (score 1):

In C++

```
std::istream is;
```

is an actual object, assigning to it will invoke the copy assignment operator which will copy the subobject of iss which is a std::istream into is and [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) it. The example linked by LogicStuff will show that you need to assign a reference or pointer to iss like so:

`std::istream &is_ref = iss;`

The difference between values, references and pointers is fundamental to C++, I would advise getting a strong grasp of [them](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Answer (score 1):

[`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) can be [constructed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream) from a [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) *(basically the device that produces or consumes characters)*. All `i/ostream` objects have an associated `std::streambuf` and can be shared.

```
std::ifstream file(this->_path); 
std::istringstream iss("str in gSo met hing");

std::istream A(iss.rdbuf());   // shares the same buffer device with iss

std::string str;

//////////////
while(A >> str) std::cout << str << " | "; //read everything from stream (~> iss)
std::cout << std::endl;

A = std::move(file);
while(A >> str) std::cout << str << " | "; //read from file, using same stream (~> file)
```

Comment: In the second case, shouldn't you call `A.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());` to share the buffer instead of transferring ownership?